# How do I get a big-picture feel for my database?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, schema, sql-server-2019, table

**Background:** I was just granted access to my company's SQL Server (MS SQL 2019 via Azure Data Studio). As I have not yet been assigned any specific projects I want start digging.

I've asked my DBA to send me any database diagrams available, to this point he hasn't located any.

**Question:** What sort of scripts can I run to better understand general table relations, primary/foreign keys, dependencies and overall database structure?

**What I've checked already:** As far as online resources go, the majority of what I've come across start with the steps to create a database / table and then go into exploratory analysis.

Comment: Have you considered creating your own diagrams using SSMS? That could be a starting point as long as relationships are defined.

Comment: @DanGuzman I've already asked my DBA about this, his response to my inquiry about database diagramming function in SSMS was. "that feature in SSMS is almost useless and needs considerable setup"...

Comment: @HoganMarhoefer Well the feature itself requires no setup (it's natively available in SSMS) but it doesn't have a lot of features. But as Dan noted, if the relationships are defined already (e.g. foreign keys), then this feature will do exactly what you're looking for. It'll show you a visualization of the relationship between tables. You're able to drag in as many of the tables in the database as you want at a time too. So as basic as it is, it is helpful from an exploratory standpoint.

Comment: @J.D. I realize that, which is why it was my go-to question for our DBA. Trust me, I'm a little bit annoyed at his response, but cannot force his hand. I will have to figure out other ways to gain an understanding of the database, describe table-relations using PKs/FKs, etc. 

I stumbled on this article [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105179/how-to-understand-a-database-that-is-already-developed ], it doesn't wholly address my issues, though.

Comment: There are plenty of easy ways to visualise the DB structure (assuming it is correctly defined).  Some Visio editions, Visual Studio, MS Access, many EA tools can all ingest & visualise PK/FKs

Comment: I looked at the SO link you found and there are a number of potentially useful scripts there. You say that it doesn't wholly address your issues. What else are you looking for that the answers in that link you found don't address? Also, I searched "mssqltips script to get primary and foreign key" and found an article that might help:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3443/script-all-primary-keys-unique-constraints-and-foreign-keys-in-a-sql-server-database-using-tsql/